# How to create a help screen like one which comes when we set up an Android Device for the very first time?

Tags: android

I am developing an App for which I want to create a help screen like one which comes when we setup an Android Device for the very first time.

Something like these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Barend But how to implement this in my App? Please explain as I am a beginner in Android Development.

Comment: Keep in mind that your app will **considerably grow in size**, by adding full screen pictures.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Ok, but how should i do this in my App. Please let me know more about it in details, explain me as a Teacher.

Comment: Do your homework as a student then and follow the links that have been given to you above and below.

Comment: I'd say that @Squonk approach is the most convincing one (no extra libs).

Answer (score 2):

There are two libraries you can use to achieve this effect which are:

[ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

[Robodemo](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo)

Try going through their samples and read about how to use them on their respective pages. If you still need any help, do let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your **precious reply** bro, but I am still unable to get that how _I would be able to make some help screens like those given in question_. I am finding myself **helpless**. Would you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: download the sample from the showcase view and try running it and if you still have problems let me know.